# How to take this board off the undercover without breaking it?

Tags: motherboard

I have this ECU on the below picture, I tried to pry it apart from the undercover with a screwdriver, but I dont want to put too much pressure so I don't break it. Any idea how to separate it? Also, is that a screw in the second image? It looks flat and there is no engraving to place the screwdriver in.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like there are plastic rivets; you'll have to break those.

Comment: It may also have some bonding agent under it which may make it difficult to remove without breaking.

Comment: that is not a screw ... it is an alignment mark etched in the copper ... what do you hope to accomplish by removing the board?

Comment: @jsotola there're capacitors and other electronic components behind the board I need to test

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two more screws to remove.
If the PCB has some kind of glue on its perimeter, try using a heat gun.
[image]

Comment: There is no engraving to torque the screwdriver